# How to use env variable inside triggers section in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Reading the properties file for the node label and triggerConfigURL, node label works, but I couldn't read and set triggerConfigURL from environment.

```
def propFile = "hello/world.txt" //This is present in workspace, and it works.
pipeline {
    environment {
        nodeProp = readProperties file: "${propFile}"
        nodeLabel = "$nodeProp.NODE_LABEL"
        dtcPath = "$nodeProp.DTC"
    }
    agent { label env.nodeLabel } // this works!! sets NODE_LABEL value from the properties file.
    triggers {
         gerrit dynamicTriggerConfiguration: 'true',
                triggerConfigURL: env.dtcPath, // THIS DON'T WORK, tried "${env.dtcPath}" and few other notations too.
                serverName: 'my-gerrit-server',
                triggerOnEvents: [commentAddedContains('^fooBar$')]
    }
    stages {
        stage('Print Env') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'env' // This prints "dtcPath=https://path/of/the/dtc/file", so the dtcPath env is set.
                }
            }
        }
```

After running the job, the configuration is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the `env` and `triggers` clauses Jenkins runs one before the other, and it looks like you have experimentally proven that `triggers` run first and `env` second. It also looks like `agent` runs after `env` as well.

While I don't know why the programmers have made this specific decision, I think you are in a kind of a chicken-and-egg problem, where you want to define the pipeline using a file but can only read the file once the pipeline is defined and running.

Having said that, the following might work:

```
def propFile = "hello/world.txt"
def nodeProp = null

node {
    nodeProp = readProperties file: propFile
}

pipeline {
    environment {
        nodeLabel = nodeProp.NODE_LABEL
        dtcPath = nodeProp.DTC
    }
    agent { label env.nodeLabel } 
    triggers {
         gerrit dynamicTriggerConfiguration: 'true',
                triggerConfigURL: nodeProp.DTC, 
//etc.
```